# padding sequence in R

Tags: r

I would like to create left padding column depending on the max number of element of a column in an efficient way.

Let me detail the input and output
My input data is this:

```
input <- data.frame(path=c("2","4,3,4","3,1"))
input
   path
1     2
2 4,3,4
3   3,1
```

expected output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  0  2
2  4  3  4
3  0  3  1
```

The logic base on the input is:

1 - We look at the row having the maximum element ( on this example it is 3 because we have 4,3,4 in row number 2) we now know that we will need to create 3 column as output

2 - for the row that doesn't have 3 element we backfill with 0.
Since the first row has only 1 element i need to put two column with 0
for the second row i can directly fill all columns because we have three elements,for the last row i have 2 elements so i need to backfill one 0.

My attempt which does the work but is dirty

```
input$path <- as.character(input$path)
lst <- strsplit(input$path, ",")
column_to_create <- max(lengths(lst))
output <- list()
i <- 1
for(i in 1:length(lst)){
  if (length(lst[[i]]) < column_to_create) {

    nb_create <- column_to_create - length(lst[[i]])
    output[[i]] <- c(rep(0,nb_create),lst[[i]])
  }
  else{
    output[[i]] <- lst[[i]]
  }

}
output <- lapply(output,as.numeric)
do.call(rbind,output)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    2
[2,]    4    3    4
[3,]    0    3    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>%
  separate(path, into=c("V1","V2","V3"), ",", fill="left") %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

`separate` by `,` into three columns, `fill` to the left if not enough pieces, replace `NA` with 0s

#### Output

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  0  2
2  4  3  4
3  0  3  1
```

#### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#### Generalizing for unknown number of columns

Iterate through each row, determine length of vector after `strsplit`, and save the `max` as `num.cols`. `paste` new column names

```
num.cols <- max(sapply(1:nrow(input), function(x) length(unlist(strsplit(as.character(input$path[x]), ",")))))
new.cols <- paste0("V", 1:num.cols)
```

Now you can use `new.cols` to define your column names

```
input %>%
  separate(path, into=new.cols, ",", fill="left") %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```